# input data from a file when each is a different type and a comma delimiter

Tags: c++

I need to read from file a series of information that is separated by commas
example

Orionis, 33000, 30000, 18, 5.9

Spica, 22000, 8300, 10.5, 5.1

i'm having a hard time figuring out the getline structure to make this work. The CS tutor,  in the lab, says to use a getline for this but i can't seem to make it work (visual studio doesn't recognize getline in this function)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "star.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char getChoice();
void processSelection(char choice);
void processA();

   (skipping crap you don't need)


static char filePath[ENTRY_SZ];

void processA() {

ifstream openFile;
long temp, test;
double lum, mass, rad;
char name;

cout << "Please enter the full file path" << endl;

cin >> filePath;

openFile.open(filePath, ios::in);

if (openFile.good() != true) {

    cout << "this file path was invalid";
}


while (openFile.good())
{
    star *n = new star;

    // getline(openFile, name, ',');
    star(name);

    getline(openFile, temp, ',');
    n->setTemperature(temp);

    getline(openFile, lum, ',');
    n->setLuminosity(lum);

    getline(openFile, mass, ',');
    n->setMass(mass);

    cin >> rad;
    n->setRadius(rad);
     }
 }
```

From what i'm reading online (including older posts) and what my CS tutor says this should work so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `getline` deals only in `string`s. You're asking it to read into a `long` (and some `double`s). What you want to is read into a `string` and then turn the `string` into a `long` with [`std::stol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) or [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol)

Comment: Does the same principal apply with char arrays (as my school doesn't allow string)?

Comment: Your school is stupid. [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) has a `char*` overload, but it's harder to use safely.

Comment: On a slightly less useless note, sorry about that, [look at `fscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf). It wanders further away from C++, but if you can't use `std::string`, you might as well go C-style. `fscanf(c-styleFileHandle, "%s, %ld, %lf, %lf, %lf\n", name, &temp,  &lum, &mass, &rad);` will do what you need.

Comment: i tried playing around with your code and can't figure what "c-styleFileHandle" should be in my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggestion to use `std::getline()` is likely implying that you'd first read a `std::string` and then deal with the content of this `std::string`, e.g., using `std::istringstream`.

I'd suggest *not* to use `std::getline()` and, of course, to also check inputs *after* they are read. To deal with the comma separator after non-`std::string` fields I'd use a custom manipulator:

```
std::istream& comma(std::istream& in) {
    if ((in >> std::ws).peek() == ',') {
        in.ignore();
    }
    else {
        in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    }
    return in;
}
```

This manipulator skips leading whitespace (using the manipulator `std::ws`) and then simply checks if the next character is a comma. If so, the comma is extracted, otherwise the stream is set into failure mode and further attempts to read will fail until the failure state is dealt with (e.g., by using `in.clear()` and probably getting rid of any offending characters).

With this manipulator it is easy to read the respective values. Note, that when switching from formatted to unformatted input it is likely necessary that leading whitespace (e.g., in this case line breaks) need to be ignored. Also, the code below first attempts to read the values and uses them only when this attempt was successful: input shall *always* be checked *after* a read attempt was made, not before!

```
// ...
long temp;
double lum, mass, rad;
std::string name;
while (std::getline(in >> std::ws, name, ',')
           >> temp >> comma
           >> lum >> comma
           >> mass >> comma
           >> rad) {
     // use the thus read values
}
```

Comment: So you _do use_  `std::getline()`, but only to get the first string in the line with a `','` as terminator.

Comment: @Bob: yes, for the string it is necessary to specify the delimiter as it would otherwise use whitespace (using a custom `std::ctype<char>` facet the definition of what's consider whitespace could be chaged, though). However, I don't read fields into strings and parse them from there.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help I truly appreciate it. I able to get your code to work after a little reading. For anyone who stumbles on this in the future with the Googling where the code says "in" is where the filepath goes.